# Create a Boxplot using gplot2 from Excel File

Tags: r, ggplot2

My goal is to create a simple boxplot using the ggplot function. I've imported the data from an excel file using read_excel. The data consists of 4 columns (corresponding to treatment) and for each row/treatment, there are around 600 values (see screenshot of head of data.frame in R). For `ggplot` however, i don't have a clue what are the x/y names of my data frame to put in the `aes()` argument and I don't know how to create x/y names for the aes function.

I just want to know what the x and y values to put in `aes()`...or how to define them if I haven't yet.
So far, code is:

```
Library(readxl)
Library(ggplot2)

CM<-read_excel(file.choose(new=FALSE))
CM<-data.frame(CM)
```

So for the graph: `ggplot(CM, aes(??,??)`

Didn't get very far...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not the format supported by [`ggplot2`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/), which follows the grammar of graphics. However, you can transform your data frame using `tidyr`, another part of `tidyverse` (of which `ggplot2` is a part). You'd have to use `gather()`, like so:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

CM2 <- CM %>%
  gather(key = "Names", value = "Values") # You get to choose these names; choose wisely. You'll use them later

ggplot(CM2, aes(x = Names, y = Values))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

I wrote the least possible unnecessary code. Also, I created a second `data.frame` called `CM2` because I don't know if you use the original later, but you can just write `CM <- CM %>% [...]` if you prefer.

You can find some reference on `tidyr` [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/).

Comment: Erico thank you very much for such a quick response! That worked very well for my data. Life saver. Best